# Default selection color when TreeView is not focused

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-7, highlight, custom-draw

How can I set the TreeView's selected node to the default `clHighlight` color when the TreeView is not focused? I tried this code in the `CustomDrawItem` and `AdvancedCustomDrawItem` events - no luck:

```
if (cdsSelected in State) then
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
```

Also tried the change the `.HideSelection` property, makes no difference, still using that very light gray color. I'm using D7.

Answer (score 1):

Source of problem found:

```
// does nothing, still grayed when losing focus
if (cdsSelected in State) then
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;

// works fine
if (cdsSelected in State) then
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := ColorToRGB(clHighlight);
```

For some reason the `clHighlight` color can not be used, probably there is some condition in the `TTreeView` code which is checking against this color and does something differently.

Comment: That's not specific to TTreeView. I would guess the handling is when the form loads properties, because you always need to do the conversion when setting them in code.